# R: Can I 'set' my dendrogram with a for loop using dendextend?

Tags: r, for-loop, cluster-analysis, dendextend

Given the `iris` data set as an example, I do Pearson clusters using `dendextend` in the following way:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dendextend)
data(iris)
newmat <- iris[,1:4]
rownames(newmat) <- paste(iris$Species, rownames(iris))

dmat <- 1 - cor(t(newmat), method="pearson")
dmat <- as.dist(dmat)
clust.obj <- hclust(dmat, method="complete")
dend.obj <- as.dendrogram(clust.obj)
numsamples <- length(rownames(newmat))
maxdist <- max(get_nodes_attr(dend.obj, "height"))

groups <- levels(iris$Species)
cols <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(length(groups), "Set1"))
myPal <- cols(length(groups))

vals1 <- grep(groups[1], labels(dend.obj), value=TRUE)
vals2 <- grep(groups[2], labels(dend.obj), value=TRUE)
vals3 <- grep(groups[3], labels(dend.obj), value=TRUE)
vals1B <- grepl(groups[1], labels(dend.obj))
vals2B <- grepl(groups[2], labels(dend.obj))
vals3B <- grepl(groups[3], labels(dend.obj))

dend.obj <- dend.obj %>%
  set("leaves_pch", 19) %>%
  set("leaves_cex", 1) %>%
  set("branches_lty", 2) %>%
  set("by_labels_branches_col", value = vals1, TF_values = c(myPal[1],Inf)) %>%
  set("by_labels_branches_lwd", value = vals1, TF_values = c(2,Inf)) %>%
  set("by_labels_branches_lty", value = vals1, TF_values = c(1,Inf)) %>%
  set("by_labels_branches_col", value = vals2, TF_values = c(myPal[2],Inf)) %>%
  set("by_labels_branches_lwd", value = vals2, TF_values = c(2,Inf)) %>%
  set("by_labels_branches_lty", value = vals2, TF_values = c(1,Inf)) %>%
  set("by_labels_branches_col", value = vals3, TF_values = c(myPal[3],Inf)) %>%
  set("by_labels_branches_lwd", value = vals3, TF_values = c(2,Inf)) %>%
  set("by_labels_branches_lty", value = vals3, TF_values = c(1,Inf)) %>%
  set("labels_colors", ifelse(vals1B, myPal[1], ifelse(vals2B, myPal[2], myPal[3]))) %>%
  set("leaves_col", ifelse(vals1B, myPal[1], ifelse(vals2B, myPal[2], myPal[3])))

png(filename="test.png", height=1200, width=400)
mar.default <- c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1
par(mar = mar.default + c(0, 0, 0, 4))
plot(dend.obj, main="test cluster", xlab="Distance", horiz=TRUE, cex.main=1, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1)
legend(maxdist, numsamples, groups, cex=1, pch=19, col=myPal)
dev.off()
```

Which produces this cluster, which I find really useful with the colors and all:

[image: test]

The problem is that now I want to encapsulate this into a function. And the length of `groups` can vary. So I need to do the `set` part of `dend.obj` inside a `for` loop or something.

Something like:

```
for (i in 1:length(groups)){
    set("by_labels_branches_col", value=grep(groups[i],labels(dend.obj),value=TRUE), TF_values=c(myPal[i],Inf)) %>%
    set("by_labels_branches_lwd", value=grep(groups[i],labels(dend.obj),value=TRUE), TF_values=c(2,Inf)) %>%
    set("by_labels_branches_lty", value=grep(groups[i],labels(dend.obj),value=TRUE), TF_values=c(1,Inf))
}
```

Which obviously does not work... And the same goes for the `ifelse` in there, which would be really tricky.

Any help would be appreciated! I have no idea how to tackle this. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you are trying to do but would it be easier if you made another function that did the set part and then apply it to however many groups there are? It might be easier to understand if you showed what you have so far for the function

Comment: Why does this "obviously" not work?

Comment: I am just trying to do the exact same, but without the knowledge that `groups` (`levels(iris$Species)`) has length 3... something that can be applied to `groups` of any length

Comment: @Anony-Mousse try the code, it gives different errors and warnings, particularly `Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values` when trying to plot it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, in case anyone is interested, what I have done at the end, which seems to be working properly, is do the `for` loop and store the commands in an `execval` variable, then run that variable with:

```
eval(parse(text=execval))
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution (although it feels like something that could probably be done without it. But you'll need another usecase to justify us going back to the question :) ) Cheers.